# MATLAB : how to split and transpose a cell array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, split, cell, transpose

I have the next cell composition (30*1 size) is important to note that is a cell array made of numbers and NOT of strings.

What I want to do is to split it first, according to the "," so each different number has to occupy a diffierent column. Like this:

[image: CELL SPLIT]

After this, I want to transpose all the numbers, so I want to have a final matrix size (7*30)

[image: CELL TRANSPOSE]

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post better example data? Maybe a smaller bit of data actually typed into your question rather than using screenshots. I can't read them.

Comment: yes, let a={12,13,14,45;4,8,nan,nan;450,2,14,nan}  And I want to create the matrix    B  [   12    13    14    45;  4     8   NaN   NaN;   450     2    14   NaN] size 3*4  and then I want to transpose it to C [    12     4     450;    13     8      2;    14     NaN    14;    45     NaN    NaN]   size 4*3.Thanks a lot @Suever

Answer (score 1):

This is my version of the solution, type this in the Command Window in Matlab:

```
>> a={12,13,14,45;4,8,nan,nan;450,2,14,nan};  %% cell array
>> b=cell2mat(a); %% convert cell array to ordinary array of the underlying data type
>> c=transpose(b) %% transpose matrix b (or use the following syntax b.')
```

**Some useful links**:

1. [cell2mat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html)
2. [transpose](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the two images that you put in your question (though they look like being in Excel to me), I suppose that you have a cell-array with 30 lists (double-array; array with entries being of type number/double). Here I put a shorter example with 2 instead of 30.

```
dataInput={[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];[0,-1,0.5,2,5,6,7]}
```

It is a `2×1 cell array` which each of its entries are a `1x7 array of doubles`. Now to answer the first part of your question, i.e. separating entries of the lists to have each number as a single cell, not the whole list of 7 numbers as one cell, I use `num2cell`. And for the second part of your question, transposing the cells, I just add `'` (single quotation).  And to mix all of these cells into single cell-array, I use brackets. So here is one way to have a `7×2 cell array` as you want.

```
dataOutput=[num2cell(dataInput{1})',num2cell(dataInput{2})']
```

You can also use the `'` operator at the end (outside), like the following.

```
dataOutput2=[num2cell(dataInput{1});num2cell(dataInput{2})]'
% or
dataOutput3=vertcat(num2cell(dataInput{1}),num2cell(dataInput{2}))'
```